# How to compile php with sqlite3 support

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, php-extension

I want to compile php sqlite3 with custom compile option. to do that I followed following steps

1. wget http://be.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.10.tar.gz
2. tar -xvf php-5.3.10.tar.gz
3. cd php-5.3.10/ext/sqlite3
4. Run phpize

But I am getting error:

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like already reported bug 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53571&edit=1.